# Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl]

Tags: maven, soap, spring-boot, cxf, pom.xml

I am creating a SpringBootApplication SOAPWebservice and i am facing some issue in starting that application. Which is trowing the following exception.
Can someoneplease assist me.

StackTrace

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'prefService' defined in class path resource [com/canaldigital/tsi/config/WebServiceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested
 exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl]: Factory method 'prefService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.ConsoleApp
ender.<init>(Lorg/apache/log4j/Layout;Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
        at com.canaldigital.tsi.config.App.main(App.java:15)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl]: Factory method 'prefService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppend
er.<init>(Lorg/apache/log4j/Layout;Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender.<init>(Lorg/apache/log4j/Layout;Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at com.canaldigital.tsi.commons.logger.CDLoggerFactory.initLog4J(CDLoggerFactory.java:26)
        at com.canaldigital.tsi.commons.logger.CDLoggerFactory.<clinit>(CDLoggerFactory.java:14)
        at com.canaldigital.tsi.creditcard.ws.CreditCard.<clinit>(CreditCard.java:68)
        at com.canaldigital.tsi.config.WebServiceConfig.prefService(WebServiceConfig.java:31)
        at com.canaldigital.tsi.config.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8155b79.CGLIB$prefService$1(<generated>)
        at com.canaldigital.tsi.config.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8155b79$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6e769f59.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
        at com.canaldigital.tsi.config.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8155b79.prefService(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 24 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

POM.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.canaldigital.tsi</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc-ws</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>abc-ws</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/>
            <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.canaldigital.tsi</groupId>
                <artifactId>tsi-creditcard-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.5</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.5</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.5</version>
            </dependency> 

        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
        <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

WebServiceConfig.java

```
package com.canaldigital.tsi.config;

import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.canaldigital.tsi.creditcard.ws.CreditCard;

@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/services/*");
    }

    @Bean
    public Bus cxf() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean
    public EndpointImpl prefService(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        Bus bus = (Bus) applicationContext.getBean(Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID);
        Object implementor = new CreditCard();
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, implementor);
        endpoint.publish("/cc");
        endpoint.getServer().getEndpoint().getInInterceptors()
                .add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
        endpoint.getServer().getEndpoint().getOutInterceptors()
                .add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got two incompatible Versions of log4j referenced that don't play well together. Use the dependency-tree function of maven to identify where this different versions come from:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

Then exclude the wrong one by using the exclude functionality of maven:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>group-of-responsible-jar</groupId>
       <artifactId>artifactId-of-responsible-jar</artifactId>
       <version>...</version>
       <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependecy>
```